# Email verification via API

Tags: laravel-7

I am trying to verify email after a user register through api, I'm able to send the verification code to email which I have the response in mailtrap, now when I click on the verify email button I get this error **call to member function getKey() on null**
this is my code

```
 public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $request->user()->getKey())) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($request->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new Response(['message' => 'Already Verified'], 204)
            : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    if ($response = $this->verified($request)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new Response(['message' => 'Successfully Verified'], 204)
        : redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);

}
```

this is the route

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Api\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
```

I am using postman to test the API since the front-end is not ready yet

this is the link sent to mailtrap

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/email/verify/3/258fb90b7a21cd79eaea6c39c88059af0090924d?expires=1589842576&signature=5a7b6463514c6dc8404f20cba54e5e8e7aae013eecec3af0e0f34d58aa7e993e

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too late to answer but I got the same problem and the only thing that resolved this for me is:

```
use App\Model\User;
```

after that in this "verify" method

```
$user = User::findOrFail($request->route("id"));
```

finally, replace $request()->user with this $user,

Answer (score 0):

If this is an authenticated user, you can try with `Auth::user()` instead of `$request->user()`